# CRM 2016 Blank Address record created in Contact entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I am facing a weird issue wherein whenever I create a contact, an empty record is created in Other Addresses entity.

Below is the screenshot -

[image]

I read on several blogs that by default 2 blank records are created every time an account or contact is created, However this does not happen in case of accounts. No blank record is seen under 'Customer Address Associated view' for Accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you read on the blogs is mostly correct:

- Two address records are automatically created for accounts.
- Three address records are automatically created for contacts.

By default, the address records that are created behind the scenes are not shown  in the *Customer Address Associated View*.

The default filter for the view can be seen below. If the filter for your view has been modified, it would explain why you see one of the three automatically created address records for contact.

```
<filter type="or">
    <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="addressnumber" operator="gt" value="2" />
        <condition attribute="objecttypecode" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="and">
        <condition attribute="addressnumber" operator="gt" value="3" />
        <condition attribute="objecttypecode" operator="eq" value="2" />
    </filter>
</filter>
```

Have a look at the following link for a more in-depth discussion of addresses in CRM: [The CRM Address Entity: There’s more to it than you think!](http://icu-mscrm.blogspot.com/2009/05/crm-address-entity-theres-more-to-it.html).
In general, I find that it often pays off to make a custom address entity if your requirements deviate from what is possible with the out-of-the-box address entity.